# Android search view in actionbar compat shows QuickAction menu, but stops getting keyboard events

Tags: android, event-handling, android-actionbar-compat, quickaction

I'm using ActionBarCompat and QuickAction (https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction also shown at http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) in my Android app.

In the right of the action bar there's the traditional search icon, user touches it, the search view expands and the user can type the queries.

I have a requirement that, instead of showing recent searches, the popup will show two items “search TYPED_TEXT in foo” and “search TYPED_TEXT in bar”, so, instead of using the default search pop up (so I won't have to deal with content providers and mock a cursor just to show the same two items).

in my `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`, the `onQueryTextChange` is overriden so when user types at least 3 chars I set up the QuickAction and show it.

```
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Context context = MyActivity.this.getBaseContext();
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rootView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.quickaction_popup, null);                 

            rootView.measure(0, 0);

            QuickActionList action = new QuickActionList(MyActivity.this,
                QuickActionList.HORIZONTAL, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            action.addActionView(rootView);
            action.show(mSearchView);            

            // [1]. I'll explain this comment line below.

            return false; // I tried with return true as well to indicate I've consumed the event here.
     }
 }
```

The problem is: after the quick action is shown, I can't type anything. I must touch the search view again to type another char.

Where I commented with `// [1]`, I tried to change focus with `setFocusable` + `requestFocus`, `setFocusableInTouchMode` + `requestFocus` and even `setFocusable` + `setFocusableInTouchMode` + `requestFocus`, but no success at all.
Here's the snippet that replaced `// [1]`:

```
mSearchView.setFocusable(true);
mSearchView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
boolean gotFocus = mSearchView.requestFocus();
Log.d("DOUG", Boolean.toString(gotFocus));
```

Log shows `gotFocus = true`, but I still can't type. I see a blue bar showing it's ready to take input, but it's not blinking. Soft keyboard keeps showing as well, but when I type, it's like I'm typing on something not editable. Probably the QuickAction is capturing the soft key event, but I couldn't find how to avoid this.

Any ideas on how to solve this or a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up modifying [PopupWindows.java](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction/blob/master/src/net/londatiga/android/PopupWindows.java) inside NewQuickAction so that `preShow` optionally accepts a parameter to tell if the popup window is focusable. Then it passes the parameter to `mWindow.setFocusable(…)`.